# Tradingview V1 to V4 iff statement conversion

Tags: python, indentation, pine-script

I'm trying to integrate TradingView's Buying Pressure and Selling Pressure script, built in Pine Script v1, into a v4 code of my own, and it's causing the error "Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation' for the iff statements below.

Could someone help me translate just these lines into v4 compatible code? I tried to fix it by changing indentation but could not success.. Below is the code. I reaaly really appreciate if someone can give me a hand. Thanks a lot in advance

```
study("BP Trial", shorttitle="BP Trial", overlay=true)
signal = input(title="Short Period Candles:", type=integer, defval=4)
vol = iff(volume > 0, volume , 1)


BP =    iff(close<open,     iff(close[1]<open,  max(high-close[1], close-low), 
                                                    max(high-open, close-low)),
            iff(close>open,     iff(close[1]>open,  high-low, 
                                                    max(open-close[1], high-low)),
            iff(high-close>close-low, iff(close[1]<open,    max(high-close[1],close-low),
                                                            high-open),
            iff(high-close<close-low, iff(close[1]>open,    high-low,
                                                            max(open-close[1], high-low)),
            iff(close[1]>open,  max(high-open, close-low),
            iff(close[1]<open,  max(open-close[1], high-low),
        high-low))))))
SP =    iff(close<open,     iff(close[1]>open,  max(close[1]-open, high-low),
                                                    high-low),
            iff(close>open,     iff(close[1]>open,  max(close[1]-low, high-close),
                                                    max(open-low, high-close)),
            iff(high-close>close-low,   iff(close[1]>open,  max(close[1]-open, high-low),
                                                            high-low),
            iff(high-close<close-low,   iff(close[1]>open,  max(close[1]-low, high-close),
                                                            open-low),
            iff(close[1]>open,  max(close[1]-open, high-low),
            iff(close[1]<open,  max(open-low, high-close),
        high-low))))))


plot(BP, style=line, color=red)
plot(SP, style=line, color=blue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use our manual https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Line_wrapping.html

```
//@version = 4
study("BP Trial", shorttitle="BP Trial", overlay=true)
signal = input(title="Short Period Candles:", type=input.integer, defval=4)
vol = iff(volume > 0, volume , 1)


BP =    iff(close<open, iff(close[1]<open,  max(high-close[1], close-low), max(high-open, close-low)),
         iff(close>open, iff(close[1]>open,  high-low, max(open-close[1], high-low)),
         iff(high-close>close-low, iff(close[1]<open, max(high-close[1],close-low), high-open),
         iff(high-close<close-low, iff(close[1]>open,    high-low,max(open-close[1], high-low)),
         iff(close[1]>open,  max(high-open, close-low), iff(close[1]<open,  max(open-close[1], high-low), high-low))))))



SP =    iff(close<open,     iff(close[1]>open,  max(close[1]-open, high-low), high-low), 
         iff(close>open,     iff(close[1]>open,  max(close[1]-low, high-close), max(open-low, high-close)),
         iff(high-close>close-low,   iff(close[1]>open,  max(close[1]-open, high-low), high-low), 
         iff(high-close<close-low,   iff(close[1]>open,  max(close[1]-low, high-close), open-low),
         iff(close[1]>open,  max(close[1]-open, high-low),
         iff(close[1]<open,  max(open-low, high-close), high-low))))))


plot(BP, color=color.red)
plot(SP, color=color.blue)
```

Comment: Wauww... I wasn't expecting an answer this fast :) Thank you very very very much :)